How to use the can() method on update routes?
I read here that in Laravel we can use the can method instead of the traditional middleware call on a route. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authorization#middleware-actions-that-dont-require-models
use App\Models\Post;
 
Route::post('/post', function () {
    // The current user may create posts...
})->can('create', Post::class);

Now the traditional method for middlewares looks like this:
Route::post('/post', function () {
    // The current user may create posts...
})->middleware('can:create,App\Models\Post');

I really like this can method and it would be nice to be able to replace middleware calls for update too to be consequent:
use App\Models\Post;
Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');

Is there a way to do this? The documentation does not contain anything about this...

Why is your core purpose? Are you using any Policy class? Through can you can authorize user's action to you DB resources.But to use can you need a Policy class.

@Subha My goal is using a Policy class with the can method of the route instead of using the middleware method.

I have posted my detailed elaborative answer, please check and let me know your feedback.

There are few steps you need to follow.
Create & get registered your Policy class.
With this command create a Policy-class. The generated policy will be placed
in the app/Policies directory.
php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post

This class look like this.
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the post.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        // Example: Only allow the user to update their own post
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}

Then register the policy-class to the boot method of your application's AppServiceProvider like this.
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Policies\PostPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    Gate::policy(Order::class, OrderPolicy::class);
}

And finally you can use the can in the route to use this PostPolicy class like this.
use App\Models\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->can('update','post'); //here `post` is an instance of `App\Models\Post` model

N:B :-

The Post model must have a foreign-key named user_id upon which update authorization will be matched.If no matched users found then an HTTP response with a 403 status will be returned.
For more information check the official docs about how to create & registered Policy
Check the Generating Policies & Registering Policies section of the docs.


Note that according to the documentation you don't have to register policies manually if you keep the naming convention. X -> XPolicy and the php file is in the Policies folder.

@inf3rno, Yes that's right and it is  mentioned in the docs.1st phrase of the Policy Discovery  section of the docs explains it.

I am sorry for out of topic. What if a user with superadmin role want to update each data ?

@Hendro, In that case you need to specify role i.e.  you can define superadmin so that he/she can have authorization to access/modify any data in DB. For other users you can define any role  other than superadmin.  You need to define this role column in users table where all the users details stored. And then same logic apply if $user->role=="superadmin" grant full access and for other users you can define it in this way..$user->role=="edit".

@Hendro, BTW you can do this by many ways, but it is hard to tell you without seeing code that which one will be appropiate.You can also do it by using third party packages like spatie/laravel-permission. Chek the link for detailed info https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

@Subha Thankyou bro

You are most welcome @Hendro.
